# Python Selenium how to disable images in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to disable images in Selenium (Python) using Firefox as webdriver and this code works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')
```

but apparently `firefox_profile` has been deprecated because I get always the same message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 3
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 8
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
```

Does anyone know how to do the same with the code updated??

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Options instead of Profile as that is old functionality that is no longer supported.

I suggest you also install webdriver manager to more easily manage your webdrivers

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

firefox_profile = Options();
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_profile, service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')
```